# Is it possiible to throw checked exception from spring-aop?

Tags: java, exception, aop, spring-aop

(Spring AOP): I know it's not...common practice, but is it possible to throw a checked exception from an advice?

Comment: It should be, but if it's not a type that the advised method declares that it can throw then it'll probably get wrapped in an unchecked wrapper. Try it and see.

Comment: I am not able to try it right now, otherwise I would not have asked...:)

Comment: No offense meant, but if you cannot even try it now, why is it relevant or urgent enough to ask now? ;-)

Comment: I am given a UndeclaredThrowableException, that extends RTE. Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

AOP methods are like any other method and can throw checked and unchecked exception.

P.S: I just tried to confirm.

Comment: weren't you given an <code>UndeclaredThrowableException</code>, that extends RTE?